# Remote Desktop (App Store version) can't connect to localhost

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, ssh-tunnel

OK we have a weird setup I know..
We create an SSH tunnel to our work network, then use RDP to connect to our workstations in the office. Our SSH client is setup to forward local post 1024 to our workstation on port 3389.
[image]

This works great with Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe), but doesn't work with the Microsoft Store version of Remote Desktop.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by reviewing an old, but related, issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259763/uwp-enable-local-network-loopback.  The command that resolved this for me is:

```
checknetisolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.RemoteDesktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer "why" but I can confirm the problem. I have captured network traffic and I see no response to initial SYN packet from Microsoft Store App. MSTSC and Store App send identical first packets for all I can tell. I tried to disable firewall on local Windows desktop which did not change anything. My only guess that App is using some different API than MSTSC to make connection so that ssh client does not see these packets even though they appear "on the wire".

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/525200)